# How to implement NOT LIKE as the search condition for containstable(Full-Text Query)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

What would be the search condition for the query below if we wanted to retrieve all the keys for which the columnName does not contain "thisWord" ?

```
SELECT [key] AS someValue 
     FROM CONTAINSTABLE ( table ,columnName, ??what goes here?? )
```

Note: This is a full-text based search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think:

```
SELECT 
   [key] 
FROM tableName 
   LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE ( tableName ,columnName, '' ) AS ct ON tableName.[key] = ct.[key]
WHERE tc.[key] IS NULL
```