# SQL Server full text search issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, containstable

I have a problem with full-text search results, I need to find rows that contain " spray " in `name` column and not contains " men " in `description` column.

```
select top 10 ftt.RANK, ID, name, description
from mod_product_all_fields
INNER JOIN containstable(mod_product_all_fields,(name),' ("spray") ' )  as ftt
    ON mod_product_all_fields.ID=ftt.[KEY]
INNER JOIN containstable(mod_product_all_fields,(description),' not ("men")   ')  as ftt2
    ON mod_product_all_fields.ID=ftt2.[KEY] 
ORDER BY ftt.RANK DESC
```

This query does not execute correctly, the debugger displays that I have a syntax error near  " not ('men') ".

If you have a solution for my issue please tell me

Thanks

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508449/how-to-implement-not-like-as-the-search-condition-for-containstablefull-text-que).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my pointer to the earlier answer about how to search for `NOT <a word>`, I think this should do the trick:

```
select top 10 ftt.RANK, ID, name, description
from mod_product_all_fields
INNER JOIN containstable(mod_product_all_fields,(name),' ("spray") ' )  as ftt
    ON mod_product_all_fields.ID=ftt.[KEY]
LEFT JOIN containstable(mod_product_all_fields,(description),' ("men") ')  as ftt2
    ON mod_product_all_fields.ID=ftt2.[KEY] 
WHERE
    ftt2.KEY IS NULL -- Eliminate matches on "men"
ORDER BY ftt.RANK DESC
```